# netbeans not all requested modules can be enabled

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

I know this question has already been posted, but the solutions provided don't work for me.
I added the `webupd8team/java` repository and installed `oracle-java8-installer` and `oracle-java8-set-default`.
I downloaded netbeans 8.1 from netbeans.org (full version), installed it but when it comes to enabling the java modules it fails, showing me a list of all the modules netbeans can't enable.

I also ran `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, which outputs

```
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode
```

JDK seems to be missing.

I get the correct output when I run both `java -version` and `javac -version`

I also tried to run the command `netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, unsuccessfully. I get an error message saying netbeans is not installed.

Now, all this only happens with the version I download from the website. When I install netbeans from the shell (`sudo apt-get install netbeans`) everything works just fine.

The thing is I need the full version from the website, because I'm working with HTML5, CSS, J2EE and GlassFish server support.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Go to /etc and open `netbeans.conf`.

> **Note**: you can find `netbeans_root_folder` with `ls -l $(which netbeans)`

Make sure the variable `netbeans_jdkhome` has the correct value, something like:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Comment: +1 Or /usr/local/java/java-8-oracle

Comment: and for openJdk => netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"

Comment: Where's the "netbeans root folder/etc"?

Comment: @fedd for **root folder** `ls -l $(which netbeans)` will give you this answer something like `/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/` can be...

Answer (score 4):

Either edit `/usr/local/netbeans-X.Y/etc/netbeans.conf` to contain

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java"
```

Or use the command:

```
/usr/local/netbeans-X.Y/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java
```

Answer (score 2):

edit /usr/local/netbeans-X.Y/etc/netbeans.conf file

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

Comment: I don't understand what is this supposed to mean. What are you reader supposed to do with the fragment `netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`? Could you please [edit] your post to explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means the netbeans.conf file (located in two places) was not set up correctly.To solve this you might do:

First: **open TERMINAL** go to /etc

```
cd /etc
```

Second: open *netbeans.conf* file as superuser (sudo):

```
sudo gedit netbeans.conf
```

Third: Edit the line wich corresponds to your JVM (Java Virtual Machine) folder. It looks like **#netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"**.

Change the local according to your JVM version.

To find out what JVM version you use, go to the JVM folder by typing in terminal:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

and see what name is folder that contains JVM. For example, mine is named **java-8-opendjdk-amd64**

Fourth: let's edit the second netbeans.conf file located at your **Netbeans installation folder**. Open a TERMINAL and type (here I'll use Netbeans 8.2 version):

```
cd /netbeans-8.2/etc
```

And open netbeans.conf file in editor as a superuse (sudo):

```
sudo gedit netbeans.conf
```

Last step: Edit the line wich corresponds to your JVM (Java Virtual Machine) folder. It looks like **#netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"**.

**Don't forget to uncomment the line by removing the # character.**

**Now save the file, close Netbeans and run it again! 
IT WORKS !**

Comment: Never ever use sudo for gui programms this way. `sudo -H gedit` better.