# "Not all requested modules can be enabled" error when starting a new Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I've installed Netbeans in Ubuntu LTS 16.04, but I'm getting a "Not all requested modules can be enabled" error at the "Finding Feature" stage (see below).

[image]

Following [netbeans not all requested modules can be enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750514/netbeans-not-all-requested-modules-can-be-enabled), I've tried to go to the `/etc` directory and find `netbeans.conf`, but I found no such file (see below).

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

This problem mostly happens when you use default settings while installing NetBeans. As a result, file `netbeans.conf` has incorrect location of `JAVA_HOME`. This issue can be easily resolved when we provide correct path for the location of `JAVA_HOME`.

1. To find location of `JAVA_HOME` on your system open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then in terminal type following command.

   > env | grep JAVA_HOME

Output will be something like this `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. Here `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` is location of JAVA_HOME.

2. Now, find the location of `netbeans.conf`. For this execute following command in terminal.

   > sudo find / -name netbeans.conf

After this enter your password. Output will be something like `/home/username/NetBeans/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf`. Exit from current running command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

3. Copy the output from terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and execute following command using the code you copied.

   > sudo gedit /home/username/NetBeans/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf

In your case replace `/home/username/NetBeans/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf` with the code you just copied by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

4. Above command will open the code in gedit. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to use find in gedit and search for `netbeans_jdkhome="`. This holds the location of `JAVA_HOME`. Replace everything after `netbeans_jdkhome="` with the location of `JAVA_HOME` found in step 1 above. Save and exit from the file.
5. Restart NetBeans and now try to make new project. If still it doesn't work, restart your system and try again.

Comment: you don't need to use sudo to edit `netbeans.conf`

Comment: When I enter this command int he terminal "env | grep JAVA_HOME" no output is shown. I am using ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

Locate your `netbeans` root folder, open the `/etc` directory, and edit `netbeans.conf`. Or from your '/usr' directory, search for `netbeans.conf`. Mine is in `/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/etc`.

Look for a line that says `netbeans_jdkhome=` and put in your jdk home folder `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131` so it looks like this:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131"
```

If you cannot edit your `netbeans.conf`, use the following command to open and edit it:

```
cd /path/to/netbeans.conf
sudo nano netbeans.conf
```

When you are done editing, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit, press <kbd>y</kbd> to save, then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm.