# NetBeans is not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, 18.04, netbeans, ide

I want to install NetBeans IDE in my Ubuntu 18.04 system. I have successfully installed JDK 8 and it is working, but when I download NetBeans, install it, and try to run it, I get this:

[image: NetBeans error]

Please help me to solve this issue!

Comment: Did you check this AskUbuntu [thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/750514/550550)?

Comment: I have also problems with netbeans on ubuntu 18.04 with the oracle jre 1.8.0. It starts, but the needed perspectives won't open (projects and files), and it will consume all of my CPU for background scanning for all of infinity or until I shut it down.

Comment: To be honest: I blame everything on GnomeShell. It is a hell of an UI and gives me headaches even at night. 18.04 is by far the worst since I am an ubuntu user (since 6.06)